# How to search a table column without whitespace and punctuation

Tags: sql-server-2008, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I am trying to search on an sql server 2008 varchar column but with all whitespace and punctuation removed

```
Query.Where(p => p.SearchName.Contains(searchInput)
```

e.g. searching for "ABC" would return rows containing any of

1. ABC
2. A B C
3. A.B.C.

I had tried to add a persisted computed column to my table containing the stripped down data but receive an error saying that the table has been created with ANSI_NULLS set to off, and thus cannot create an index.

```
ALTER TABLE Example
ADD Name_Search AS dbo.RemoveNonAlphaNumericCharacters(Name)
PERSISTED

Msg 1935, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot create index. Object 'Example' was created with the following SET options off: 'ANSI_NULLS'.
```

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution I went for was to create a new table Example_Search and ran a data migration script to populate this with existing data (~700k records). I also created Triggers on the original table for any new/updated data coming in.

I created a UDF to strip all unwanted characters and populated an indexed column with this.

```
-- Function to remove all whitespace and punctuation from string
Create Function [dbo].[fn_RemoveNonAlphaNumericCharacters](@Temp VarChar(1000))
Returns VarChar(1000)
With Schemabinding
AS
Begin

Declare @KeepValues as varchar(50)
Set @KeepValues    = '%[^a-z0-9]%'
While PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
    Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')

Return @Temp
End
GO

ALTER TABLE Example_Search
ADD Name_Search varchar(50) NOT NULL
GO
```

In my .Net query I changed the entity collection to this new table, and also stripped out all unwanted characters from the input search term.

```
var compareName = Regex.Replace(searchName, @"\W", string.Empty);

query.Where(p => p.SearchNames.Any(n => n.NameSearch.Contains(compareName)));
```